# Wi-Fi browsing history

Tags: wireless, command-line, internet

Is there a way of viewing a Wi-Fi network's browsing history?
(probably using the command line) 
Is there a package which serves this purpose?
My OS is Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the logging capability of the router which serves the network. Once you have found how to see that log, capture it and then study it at your leisure.

Comment: I'm extremely unfamiliar with networks ... so how do I access the router and see the logging capabilities? (I'm not doing this for a malicious purpose haha)

Answer (score 0):

A more "network-based" solution would be to use `tcpdump` to study outgoing HTTP packets :

```
sudo tcpdump 'port 80' -i wlan0 # [Some parsing pipes here...]
```

This only applies to your local machine, but everything else would depend on your router's capabilities, which would be gladly appreciated in your question ;)